# My console default vpc network is different from my cli default vpc network

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I created an aws account and then logged in using the aws-cli, The problem is that the default vpc network on the console and the one displayed by the aws-cli is totally different what could be the problem

when I run aws ec2 decribe-vpcs it gives a different vpc to the one on the console

Comment: Can you provide more information on this. How many VPCs do you own? Are they in the same region?

Answer (score 2):

Your default region is configured when you configure the AWS CLI credentials. You can either run `aws configure` again or you can manually edit the file at `~/.aws/config`.

Another option is to pass the region with `--region` parameter when running the  aws ec2 decribe-vpcs command.